# Chart.js Plugin Not Recognized as Options Property in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, plugins, chart.js

Having trouble using the 'dragData' plugin using Chart.js 2.9.3 in Angular: https://github.com/chrispahm/chartjs-plugin-dragdata

Imported plugin: `chartjs-plugin-dragdata`.
Added `dragdata` to options:

```js
this.comboChart1 = new Chart("bar1", {
  type: "bar",

  options: {

    dragData: true,

    onDragStart: function (e) {
    },

    onDrag: function (e, datasetIndex, index, value) {
      // console.log(datasetIndex, index, value)
    },

    onDragEnd: function (e, datasetIndex, index, value) {
      // console.log(datasetIndex, index, value)
    },
    //Set Formatting

  },
```

However, 'dragData' is not recognized as a chart option. Following is the error message:

```
Type '{ plugins: { zoom: { pan: { enabled: true; mode: string; sensitivity: number; }; zoom: { enabled: true; mode: string; sensitivity: number; }; }; }; responsive: true; title: { display: true; text: any; position: "top"; fontSize: number; }; ... 6 more ...; onDragEnd: (e: any, datasetIndex: any, index: any, value: any)...' is not assignable to type 'ChartOptions'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'dragData' does not exist in type 'ChartOptions'.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(278, 9): The expected type comes from property 'options' which is declared here on type 'ChartConfiguration'

Receiving the following error:
index.d.ts(278, 9): The expected type comes from property 'options' which is declared here on type 'ChartConfiguration'
```

---

**Update:** Issue has been resolved. Two steps to resolve:  1. Downgrade plugin to 1.1.13 for Chart.js 2.9.3 compatibility.   2. Extend the chartOptions interface. After adding the missing properties: dragdata, ondragstart, ondrag, ondragend, the plugin started working with the options code above.

Answer (score 1):

2 things, plugin options have to be defined in the `plugins` section of the `options` object like so:

```js
new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: data,
  options: {
    plugins: {
      dragData: {
        onDragStart: function () {},
        onDragEnd: function () {},
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Second part is that since you use chart.js version 2 you might need to downgrade your drag plugin since the latest version is for V3, the latest drag version you can use is version: `1.1.13`, you can get this version by changing it directly in your `package.json` and running npm install again

Comment: Thank you LeeLenalee! This helped me solve the problem. Part of the issue was simply needing to downgrade to 1.1.13 as you mentioned. However, to resolve the 'property not found' error I extended the chartOptions interface located in index.d.ts. After adding the missing properties: dragdata, ondragstart, ondrag, ondragend, the plugin started working.